# Prove that it is NOT true that for every integer $n$, 60 divides $n$ if and only if 6 divides $n$ and 10 divides $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

This is Velleman's exercise 3.4.26 (b):

> Prove that it is NOT true that for every integer $n$, 60 divides $n$ iff 6 divides $n$ and 10 divides $n$.

I do understand that a number will be divisible by 6 and 10 if it is divisible by 60 and that it will not necessarily be divisible by 60 if it is divisible by 6 and by 10. 30 is an example of it.

I still have an issue actually discovering and writing up the proof. To illustrate the issue and to put the question in context, I would like to refer to the first part of the question already asked by another user, [Velleman's exercise 3.4.26 (a)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342128/for-every-integer-n-15-mid-n-iff-3-mid-n-and-5-mid-n). Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing more to understand. It's all in the counterexample. It is not complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the number $30$. It is divisible by $6$ and $10$ and not by $60$. We have found a counterexample and therefore the statement is not true.

---

The statement $ab$ divides $n$ if and only if $a$ divides $n$ and $b$ divides $n$ is only true if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime (share no prime factors).

Otherwise we can take the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$, this number will be smaller than $ab$ (since they are not relatively prime) and it will be divisible by $a$ and $b$. The least common multiple will always be a counterexample if $a$ and $b$ are not relatively prime.

Comment: If 30 is a contradiction, your proof is over. Simple as that. But is suppose what you want is a more mathematical justification, ask that in your question.

Comment: well, I found that 30 contradicts it ( and wrote it down). I need a well written proof that it is not true ...

Comment: "The statement is false since $30$ is a counterexample" This is a well written proof.

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is of a more general nature. Imagine it would be difficult to discover the counterexample. How would I proceed?

Comment: Here is a link to the first part of the question by another user: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342128/for-every-integer-n-15-mid-n-iff-3-mid-n-and-5-mid-n . That link is Velleman's exercise 3.4.26 (a)

Comment: Writing up a solution to that question is harder since the statement turns out to be true.

Comment: If I apply the selected answer to the problem in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342128/for-every-integer-n-15-mid-n-iff-3-mid-n-and-5-mid-n then my question would also turn out true. Do you understand?

Comment: The result is only true if the two numbers are relatively prime, $3$ and $5$ are relatively prime, while $6$ and $10$ are not.

Comment: Thank you dream. The thing with the primes explains a lot now. If you want to edit your answer... ? I will accept it then.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, I added the thing about relatively prime.

Comment: @Eugene It has nothing to do with primes per se, but whether those two numbers are "relatively prime", meaning their GCD is equal to 1.